# Change Icon of a page every 5 mins

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to write a script in `Ionic` to refresh a page every 5 minutes or to call the API every 5 minutes. I have tried to use the `$interval` function but it didn't work. Can anyone give me ideas on where to and how to start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($interval, $window) {
        $interval(function () {
      // loading page again
      // $window.location.reload();
      //you can modify it as you needd
      console.log('called in 5 seconds for 5 minutes change 5000 to  1000*60*5');
  }, 5000);
    });
</script>

<body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myCtrl">


</body>
</html>
```

### Edited

```
 $interval(function () {
      // loading page again
      // $window.location.reload();
      //you can modify it as you needd
      $scope.timer = $scope.timer + 5000;
      console.log('called in 5 seconds for 5 minutes change 5000 to  1000*60*5');
  }, $scope.timer);
```

Comment: is there a way i can delay the timer if I needed to ?

Comment: change 5000 to  1000*60*5' for 5 min interval

Comment: I changed the number to a variable, $scope.timer, and i want to delay the time and add to it in another function. I tried $scope.timer += 5000; but it didn't work, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need:

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('test', function ($interval, $timeout, $window) {
    //$timeout( function () {
      $interval(function () {
        // Refresh page
        $window.location.reload();
        // Or call api
        //$http({
        //})
      }, 1000*60*5);
    //}, 1000);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
</div>
```

Comment: is there anyway to delay the timer ?